# How to get the file handle in vb .net

Tags: vb.net, winapi, file-io, ntfs

I want to use the GetFileInformationByHandle function under kernel32.dll in order to get the NTFS unique file identifier.
The function declaration is like this :

```
Declare Auto Function GetFileInformationByHandle Lib "kernel32.dll" _ 
(ByVal hFile As IntPtr, ByRef lpFileInformation As BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION) As Boolean
```

My question may sound stupid but, how do I get the file handle (hFile As IntPtr) for a given filename in visual basic ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [FileStream.SafeFileHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.safefilehandle.aspx) property:

```
Using fs As FileStream = New FileStream("c:\test.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
    Dim hFile = fs.SafeFileHandle.DangerousGetHandle()
    ' do something
End Using
```